# Unable to parse date from String using FastDateFormat

Tags: java, date

I am using the following snippets in order to obtain Date from String.

```
//class  org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat
FastDateFormat fdf = FastDateFormat.getInstance("yyyyww");
Object ob = fdf.parseObject("201701", new ParsePosition(1));
java.util.Date d = (java.util.Date) ob;
System.out.println(d);
```

Also done the using by calling the parseObject(String) method. But upon investigating the API code I found out that it creates PArsePosition object, whilst passing 0 in its constructor which has been dealt in code so as to throw an exception.

```
//class  org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat
FastDateFormat fdf = FastDateFormat.getInstance("yyyyww");
Object ob = fdf.parseObject("201701", new ParsePosition(1));
java.util.Date d = (java.util.Date) ob;
System.out.println(d);
```

The documentation below mentions that there exists parse() method, but there isn't available.

[FastDateFormat documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.text.ParsePosition-)

Making use of parseObject() gives results as mentioned above.

The parseObject() method in API is as follows that always returns null.

[image: definition of parseObject(String,ParsePosition) in API]

Please advise on alternate approach or some stable version.

Comment: What is `201701`? If that's year and month, your pattern is wrong (it should be `yyyyMM` instead of `yyyyww`): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: And if the `parse` method is not available, maybe you're not using the same version that the documentation refers to.

Comment: @Hugo The format is year and week. Ok, looking into further versions(this one is 2.6).

Comment: I could find the `parse` method in version 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wrt upgraded version got resolved.

We actually use Maven for obtaining the dependencies. It exists for the following :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

while earlier I was struggling to do it with :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

It was a versioning problem and perhaps more of an issue whilst using Maven.

Thank you @Hugo for your assistance in question comments.

Answer (score 0):

Got this error also on pre-lollipop device KK 4.4.4.
Use SimpleDateFormat.

Example:

```
SimpleDateFormat ISO8601DATEFORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.GERMANY);
                String date = dateString.replaceAll("\\+0([0-9]){1}\\:00", "+0$100");
                return ISO8601DATEFORMAT.parse(date);
```